# Convert time_t to string and string to time_t gives wrong year and an hour

Tags: c++, string, time-t

I'm trying and trying to write functions to help myself easily convert `string` to `time_t` and `time_t` to `string`. However, it always gives me wrong a year and a wrong hour. What's wrong?

**I need it to be OS independent!**

For instance, for date `30/11/2012:09:49:55` it gives `30/11/3912:08:49:55` instead of `30/11/2012:09:49:55`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

time_t string_to_time_t(string s)
{
    int yy, mm, dd, hour, min, sec;
    struct tm when;
    long tme;

    memset(&when, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
    sscanf(s.c_str(), "%d/%d/%d:%d:%d:%d", &dd, &mm, &yy, &hour, &min, &sec);

    time(&tme);
    when = *localtime(&tme);
    when.tm_year = yy;
    when.tm_mon = mm-1;
    when.tm_mday = dd;
    when.tm_hour = hour;
    when.tm_min = min;
    when.tm_sec = sec;

    return mktime(&when);
}

string time_t_to_string(time_t t)
{
    char buff[20];
    strftime(buff, 20, "%d/%m/%Y:%H:%M:%S", localtime(&t));
    string s(buff);
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    string s = "30/11/2012:13:49:55";

    time_t t = string_to_time_t(s);
    string ss = time_t_to_string(t);

    cout << ss << "\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define "wrong". What _is_ the result? Did you read the documentation for the functions that you're using?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: edited my question with an example

Comment: [try](https://ideone.com/Sv5MBr) `when.tm_year = yy-1900;` ([reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/)).

Comment: FYI as is this will not compile on MSVS 2015.

Comment: It compiles with no errors on Kubuntu 14.04 with newest g++/gcc. And on Windows with newest Code::Blocks, so ...

Comment: Okay, so the answer to my second question is "no".

Comment: try this:     time_t SetTime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int min, int sec)
    {
        time_t rawtime;
        struct tm * timeinfo;
    
        time ( &rawtime );
        timeinfo = gmtime ( &rawtime );
        timeinfo->tm_year = year - 1900;
        timeinfo->tm_mon = month - 1;
        timeinfo->tm_mday = day;
        timeinfo->tm_hour = hour;
        timeinfo->tm_min = min;
        timeinfo->tm_sec = sec;
        return mktime ( timeinfo );
    }

Comment: @wendelbsilva fixed the year issue, but you also have to deal with how midnight is handled. You might take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321849/strptime-equivalent-on-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `tm_year` in the structure `std::tm` keeps the years since [1900](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm).

Thus, instead of `when.tm_year = yy;` its necessary to subtract 1900 from the year: `when.tm_year = yy-1900;`

You can check the code running [here](https://ideone.com/Sv5MBr).

Edit: as sfjac pointed out, my answer wasnt addressing the DST problem.

The problem with the hour is the DST flag. Since I can't reproduce the problem on ideone, only locally.. the system may be setting the `tm_isdst` based on [local settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533322/mktime-and-tm-isdst-flag).

You will need to set the `when.tm_isdst` to 0 or negative, depending on what you want. Set to 0 if you know the datetime doesnt have DST, -1 (negative) if it is unknown.